# How to control the positions of contour labels?

Tags: plotting, labeling

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + 5 y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20}, 
  ContourLabels -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ContourShading -> None]
```

gives result

[image]

But I want result like this

[image]

So I hope this code will work

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + 5 y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20}, 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#1, 0}, Background -> White] &), 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ContourShading -> None]
```

But it didn't, it gives result

[image]

**So how to control the position of `ContourLabels`?**

Comment: None of the workarounds offered in the answers (so far) explains why `ContourPlot` is giving the wrong coordinate for `14`. What am I missing?

Comment: @rhermans - Unlike for the other labels, the default location for the label 14 is far from the x=0 (semi-major) axis so that when its y coordinate is just changed to zero without also correcting the x coordinate it ends up in the wrong position. The problem is not with `ContourPlot` but rather with the manual positioning of that label.

Comment: @Bob_Hanlon, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

This can done with `Epilog`.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 5 y^2;
contours = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20};
lblXY = {#, 0} & /@ (Solve[f[x, 0] == #, x][[2, 1, 2]] & /@ contours // N);

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2},
  Contours -> contours,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  ContourShading -> None,
  Epilog -> {Thread[Text[contours, lblXY, Background -> White]]}]
```

[image: contours]

Answer (score 8):

Kind of a hack but this is what I would do.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 5 y^2;
c = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20};
labelPos = Solve[f[x, 0] == #, x][[2, 1, 2]] & /@ c;

Show[
 ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> c, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None],
 Graphics[Text[#[[2]], {#[[1]], 0}, {0, 0}, Background -> White]] & /@
   Transpose[{labelPos, c}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yes another workaround

```
Show@{ContourPlot[x^2 + 5 y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> Range[2, 20, 2], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ContourShading -> None, ImageSize -> 640],
  ContourPlot[x^2 + 5 y^2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -0.0001, 0.0001}, 
   Contours -> Range[2, 20, 2], 
   ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &), 
   ContourShading -> None]}
```

[image]

I decrease the possible region for labels by the second `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 4):

```
f = x^2 + 5 y^2;
ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20},
 ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {Max[x /. Solve[f == #3 /. y -> 0, x]], 0},
   Background -> White] &),
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Use

```
ContourLabels -> (Text[#3,  Max[x /. Solve[(f /. y -> x/3) == #3, x]] {1, 1/3}, 
  Background -> White] &)
```

to get

[image]

**Update:** you can also post-process the `ContourPlot` output to modify the location of the labels:

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 + 5 y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ContourLabels -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ContourShading -> None]; 

Normal[cp] /. Tooltip[a_, b_] :> {a, 
   Text[Style[b, 16], 
    Nearest[{1, 2 GoldenRatio} # & /@ a[[-1, 1]], {.5, 0}, 1][[1]], 
    Background -> White]}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I liked the answer, where the labels were printed on the diagonal,  but such placing can often lead to overlapping of some labels, so, I modified it to add random shifts:
(the example is in my context)

```
labelfunction := (Shift = RandomReal[{-30, 30}]; 
Text[#3, {e, 100 - e/3 + Shift} /.FindRoot[(ff - #3, {e,100}]]) & ;
ContourPlot[... , ContourLabels -> labelfunction]
```