# How-to position ContourLabel outside the Frame and Overlay ArrayPlot with ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

This is a follow-up to the question I have left earlier today. Now, thanks to @kglr I made some progress on my mini project. This said, there are still a few things that I want to do with it, and I can't seem to find a solution myself, here on stackexchange.

Here is the updated code...

```
(* work-in-progress *)
data3 = Outer[{#1, #2, #1*#2} &, Subdivide[.02, 1, 4], 
   Subdivide[10000, 10^7, 4]] // Flatten[#, 1] &
grid = Reverse @ {
    {Green, Green, Green, Yellow, Yellow},
    {Green, Green, Yellow, Yellow, Orange},
    {Green, Yellow, Yellow, Orange, Orange},
    {Yellow, Yellow, Orange, Orange, Red},
    {Yellow, Orange, Orange, Red, Red}
    };

Overlay[{
  ArrayPlot[
   grid
   , Mesh -> All
   ],
  ListContourPlot[
   data3
   , Frame -> True
   , Contours -> {300000, 600000, 900000, 1600000, 2200000}
   , ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}
   , ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, 
       Background -> White] &)
   , ContourShading -> None
   , ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}
   ]
  }]
```

It produces the following plot...

[image]

Now, I would like to overlay the `ListContourPlot` over the `ArrayPlot`. However, it seems like I am getting some misalignment which I can't seem to fix. I would also like to move the `ContourLabels` at the right side of the frame near their designated contours. I have tried a few things but also failed to achieve the desired effect. I would appreciate your help, any help would be great!

EDIT 0x

Following is the desired label placement

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite difficult to get the alignments right using `Overlay`. You can use one of the following approaches instead:

#### Inset

You can use a combination of [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) and [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

```
ap = ArrayPlot[grid, Mesh -> All];

ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Contours -> {300000, 600000, 900000, 1600000, 2200000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All},
 ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &),
 ContourShading -> None, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}, 
 Prolog -> Inset[ap, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

#### RescalingTransform

An alternative approach: Rescale the graphics primitives of `ap` using the `PlotRange`s of `ap` and `lcp`:

```
lcp = ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Contours -> {300000, 600000, 900000, 1600000, 2200000}, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All},
   ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, 
       Background -> White] &), ContourShading -> None, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}];

rT = RescalingTransform[PlotRange[ap], PlotRange[lcp]];

rescaledap = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, rT] &, ap, {1}];

Show[lcp, Prolog -> First @ rescaledap]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

#### Raster

A much simpler way is to use [`Raster`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html) and use `GridLines` instead of `Mesh`:

```
Show[lcp, Prolog -> 
  Raster[Reverse@grid /. RGBColor -> List, Transpose@PlotRange[lcp]], 
 GridLines -> (Subdivide[##, 5] & @@@ PlotRange[lcp])]
```

[image]

#### Modifying contour labels

Using a slight modification of the function `modifyLabels` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161550/125) we can place the contour labels nest to the right frame:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

ClearAll[modifyLabels]
modifyLabels[styles__: 14] := Quiet[Normal[#] /. {Text[__] :> Sequence[], 
     t : Tooltip[a_, b_] :> 
       {t, Text[Framed[Style[b, {a[[-2]], styles}], Background -> White], 
        LineScaledCoordinate[SortBy[First]@a[[-1, 1]], 1], Right]}}] &

modifyLabels[] @ ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Contours -> {300000, 600000, 900000, 1600000, 2200000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0,1}, All},
  ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}, ContourLabels -> All, 
  ContourShading -> None, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}, 
  Prolog -> Inset[ap, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

With further tweaking:

```
ClearAll[modifyLabels2]
modifyLabels2[styles__: 14] := 
 Quiet[Normal[#] /. {Text[__] :> Sequence[], 
     t : Tooltip[a_, b_] :> {t, 
       Text[Pane[Framed[Style[b, {a[[-2]], styles}], Background -> White], 
         ImageMargins -> {{12, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
        LineScaledCoordinate[SortBy[First]@a[[-1, 1]], 1], Left]}}] &

modifyLabels2[]@
 ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Contours -> {300000, 600000, 900000, 1600000, 2200000}, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}, ContourLabels -> All, 
  ContourShading -> None, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}, 
  Prolog -> Inset[ap, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[1]], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All},
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 90}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why `Overlay` is so picky? :D I spent an hour tinkering with it. So, I am impressied with the above. Also, any ideas how I could align the `CountourLabels` at the right side of the `Frame`?

Comment: @e.doroskevic, maybe the price we pay for being able to overlay arbitrary objects:)  By _the raight side og the `Frame`_, do you mean the label frames  or the plot  frame (i.e. place labels at the right end of the associated contour line)?

Comment: It does make sense. I mean, I have learned a lot from today alone, and it has been a pleasent experience getting back to Mathematica. I do appreciate all the help. I have dropped a screenshot with a reference to the label placement. I should have formulated it better :D

Comment: @e.doroskevic, please see the update re placement of labels.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you! :D I spent the whole day on this thing

Answer (score 5):

I thought it would be interesting to see how one could use `DataRange` to align the `ArrayPlot` with the contour plot using `Show`.

It could have been straight forward. Let `lcp` be the contour plot, then:

```
{xrange, yrange} = PlotRange /. Options[lcp];

ap = ArrayPlot[
      grid
      , Mesh -> All
      , DataRange -> {xrange, yrange}
      ];
Show[lcp, ap, lcp]
```

[image: Output]

Alas, the squares are centered on their values, so half of the outer squares are outside of the view. (Actually a bit less than half, considering the plot range padding.)

```
{xrange, yrange}
```

> `{{0.02, 1.}, {4., 7.}}`

The `DataRange` option is currently saying that we should place, on the x-axis, the middle of the leftmost square at 0.02 and the middle of the rightmost square at 1, and correspondingly for the y-axis.

We can fix this by adjusting the data range. Currently, we have a total of four squares in view, covering $1 - 0.02 = 0.98$ units of length along the x-axis.

We need to offset the middle of the square along the x-axis precisely the amount it takes to move the entire square into the view. We can set up an equation to figure out what the amount shoud be:

$$
(1 - x) - (0.02 +x) = \frac{4}{5} (1 - 0.02)\implies x = 0.098
$$

and similarly for the y-axis:

$$
(7 - x) - (4 + x) = \frac{4}{5} (7 - 4)\implies x = 0.3
$$

Putting these offsets into the code, we get

```
ap = ArrayPlot[
      grid
      , Mesh -> All
      , DataRange -> {xrange + {0.098, -0.098}, yrange + {0.3, -0.3}}
      ];
Show[lcp, ap, lcp]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I like it! It's actually a clever way to use `DataRange` :O I have learned something new!