# How to show numbers on the borders of contours in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

Consider

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x/4] + Cos[y/4], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The output is

[image]

How can I put numbers on the borders of each contour, so that I don't need the legend bar? If possible, I'd like to know how to customize the color of numbers, so that they are easily visible.

Comment: Add the option `ContourLabels->True`?

Comment: How to adjust the color, size, and position of numbers?

Comment: also related: [Label some contourplots individually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161507/125) and [Colour of contour labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139839/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employing the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163858/22013):

```
g = Cos[x/4] + Cos[y/4];

ContourPlot[g, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[Style[#3, 12, Red]], 
      Max[x /. Solve[(g /. y -> x) == #3, x] /. C[1] -> 0] {1, 1}, 
      Background -> White] &), 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]] // Quiet
```

[image]